# Update the current session's default parameter value to reflect a new default

Tags: postgresql, configuration

Say I `ALTER` the database default `search_path` to include a new schema:

```
ALTER DATABASE my_db SET search_path TO "$user",public,other_schema;
```

Then I also update the current `search_path` to match:

```
SET search_path "$user",public,other_schema;
```

This is great. Now I can use objects from that schema in my current session without including the schema.

...unless someone `RESET`s the parameter:

```
RESET search_path;
```

This doesn't reset it back to the new default. It resets it back to the original default before the session started. Even `COMMIT`ing the current transaction doesn't change this.

Trying to `UPDATE pg_settings` doesn't work:

```
UPDATE pg_settings SET reset_val = '"$user",public,other_schema' WHERE name = 'search_path';
SELECT * FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'search_path';
```

This shows no change to the view and no difference in the behavior of `RESET`.

I could see use cases for this, but in my use case, I need this to not happen. How can I get PostgreSQL to update the current session default alongside my other changes, so that `RESET` will set it back to that value? Especially following a `COMMIT`?

Comment: If you're wondering what in the heck I'm doing, I'm trying to work around [this issue](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1379) in Flyway.

Answer (score 0):

`DATABASE`-level default settings take effect upon connecting. You need to reconnect for the new database defaults to become your connection defaults (if they are not overridden on the database+role level).

From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-config.html):

> This will save the setting (but not set it immediately). In subsequent connections to this database it will appear […]